# Outlook error Retrieving the COM class factory

Tags: outlook, uac, com-automation

We have a functionality to add contacts to outlook.

I simply want to do it to existing outlook process if one is running or open if not running.

I get error:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).in case the process in not
>   already running.

Note: the below method is called 2 times.

My code is:

```
Private Sub InitObject()
    If (Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK").Count > 0) Then
        objOutlook = DirectCast(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application"), Outlook.Application)
        'If objOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Else
        objOutlook = New Outlook.Application()
    End If
    If objNamespace Is Nothing Then
        objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
        objNamespace.Logon("", "", False, False)
    End If

    If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(10)
    End If
End Sub
```

I read several posts on this saying admin privileges and all. Now I am running Visual Studio without Admin rights. I am sacred is this error will be seen in production too where we don't use Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

What Outlook version do you have installed on the problematic PC? Is it the Click2Run edition of Outlook 2010?

Anyway, I see two possible causes for that:

1. You have got the Click2Run edition of Office 2010 installed on the PC. The fact is that the Click2Run edition of Office 2010 doesn't support automation. See [Office 2010 Click-to-Run compatibility with add-ins](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/982431) for more information. Also you may find the [How to: Verify Whether Outlook Is a Click-to-Run Application on a Computer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864733.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article.
2. Your program and MS Outlook must both be run as administrator or as normal privilege level. They should be under the same privileges. You may find the [How to self-elevate an application to a high privilege level under UAC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/981778?wa=wsignin1.0) article helpful.

Be aware, Outlook is a singleton. I.e. if it is already running, you will get a pointer to the already running instance when you create a new Outlook Application instance.

Comment: 2. was it. I was running the app in Admin Mode and received this error message:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)